# How can I delete a row in a Pandas dataframe if the entire row is null?

Tags: python, pandas

I have been checking each value of each row and if all of them are null, I delete the row with something like this:

```
df = pandas.concat([df[:2], df[3:]])
```

But, I am thinking there's got to be a better way to do this. I have been trying to use a mask or doing something like this:

```
rows_to_keep  = df.apply(
    lambda row : 
      any([if val is None for val in row ])
   , axis=1)
```

I also tried something like this (suggested on another stack overflow question)

```
pandas.DataFrame.dropna()
```

but don't see any differences in my printed dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dropna` returns a new DataFrame, you probably just want:

```
df = df.dropna()
```

or

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

If you have a more complicated mask, `rows_to_keep`, you can do:

```
df = df[rows_to_keep]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I tried: df=df.dropna(axis=1,how='all'), however, I think it is not working because I have perhaps some string/unicode (? is this possible?). It is from a webscrape. I will investigate more carefully.